# What is the difference between "every four months" and "every fourth month"?

Tags: numbers

For example:
It is January now.

- The test is to be done every four  months.
- The test is to be done every fourth month.

Which month would the test be done?

Comment: Why do you think those are different months?

Answer (score 2):

> every 4 month*s*

(note the extra 's') would mean with an interval of 4 months, so January, May, September, January next year etc.

> every 4th month

is almost never used; one would assume that *every 4th month of the year*, so that would be in April each year. However, a more common way to say that would be

> every year in April

You *might* misheard the latter option, and it could be

> every 4th *of the* month

instead. That just means every 4th *day* of the month, so January 4th, February 4th, March 4th, etc.

Comment: Glorfindel; Ramanujan, can you support ‘(In) every 4th month means … in April of every year,' please?

Even in specifically discussing term payments with people like landlords and estate agents, accountants, book-keepers, revenue officers and company secretaries I haven’t heard any such thing.

To me it's obvious that 'every year in April' just might grammatically come from 'the fourth month every year’, which is very different and also almost never used: it would needlessly complicate a simple issue; 'every April' would always be preferred.

No; the examples are virtually synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

In that case,every 4 months means test to be done in April,august and December.

In every 4th month means test to be done in April of every year.